# Converts Degrees/Minutes/Seconds to Decimals using SQL

Tags: sql

Is there any SQL script that converts Degrees/Minutes/Seconds (saved in Column A) to Decimals (to be saved in new Column B)? I googled for existing solutions, but all examples refer to Decimals->Deg/Min/Sec. I appreciate any example, because I'm not strong in SQL scripting.

Comment: Wait, how are those three values saved in _one_ column?  And presumably this is a **math** problem first, not an SQL one.

Comment: @X-Zero: Unfortunately,they are saved in one column as e.g. 41.182973. If degrees, minutes and seconds would be saved in separate columns, then I could simply divide minutes by 60 and seconds by 3600.

Comment: How is 41.182973 degrees/minutes/seconds?  That's what I would expect to be in decimal.

Comment: @Stark - Agreed, that appears to be decimals.  Especially because there are only 60 seconds in a minute (not 73)...

Comment: @stark: No,it was originally written as 41 18' 29.73. Then this was combined into a single column in SQL table. So, it seems to be confusing, but it's deg/min/sec.

Comment: I suspect it's stored as a number.  This is the same way that degrees-minutes-seconds values were stored by HP-41C calculators, which I used to solve navigation and maneuvering problems back when I was in the Navy 30 years ago.  (Dang!  Tempus fugit! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
SELECT DMS, DEGREES + (MINUTES / 60) + (SECONDS / (60 * 60)) AS DECIMAL_DEGREES
  FROM (SELECT DMS,
               TRUNC(DMS) AS DEGREES,
               TRUNC((DMS - TRUNC(DMS)) * 100) AS MINUTES,
               ((DMS * 100) - TRUNC(DMS * 100)) * 100 AS SECONDS
          FROM TEST_DMS)
```

or, if you prefer it all as one expression:

```
SELECT DMS,
       TRUNC(DMS) +
         (TRUNC((DMS - TRUNC(DMS)) * 100) / 60) +
         (((DMS * 100) - TRUNC(DMS * 100)) * 100) / (60 * 60) AS DECIMAL_DEGREES
  FROM TEST_DMS
```

At the very least these agree with the results returned by my trusty, rusty HP-41C.  :-)

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project...I used script to solve issue on DMS conversion on oracle db

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN LENGTH(longitude)=7 THEN ROUND (cast(substr(longitude, 1, 1) as numeric(10,5)) +  cast(substr(longitude, 3, 2) as numeric(10,5))/60 +  cast(substr(longitude, 6, 2) as numeric(10,5))/3600,4) 
WHEN LENGTH(longitude)=8  THEN ROUND (cast(substr(longitude, 1, 2) as numeric(10,5)) +  cast(substr(longitude, 4, 2) as numeric(10,5))/60 +  cast(substr(longitude, 7, 2) as numeric(10,5))/3600,4)
ELSE
ROUND (CAST (longitude as Numeric(10,5)),4)
END AS LONGITUDE,
CASE
WHEN LENGTH(latitude)=7 THEN ROUND (cast(substr(latitude, 1, 1) as numeric(10,5)) +  cast(substr(latitude, 3, 2) as numeric(10,5))/60 +  cast(substr(latitude, 6, 2) as numeric(10,5))/3600,4) 
WHEN LENGTH(latitude)=8  THEN ROUND (cast(substr(latitude, 1, 2) as numeric(10,5)) +  cast(substr(latitude, 4, 2) as numeric(10,5))/60 +  cast(substr(latitude, 7, 2) as numeric(10,5))/3600,4)
ELSE
ROUND (CAST (latitude as Numeric(10,5)),4)
END AS LATITUDE
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the below to do the same

```
declare @cord  varchar (max)

set  @cord=  '2504N 05534E'

select

case when  CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)>0 then
case when  right(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),1) = 'N' then
(left(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),2))
+
(SUBSTRING(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),3,2)/60.0)
else
-1*(
(left(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),2))
+
(SUBSTRING(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),3,2)/60.0)
)
end
end latitude
,case when  CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)>0 then
 case when right(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1),100))),1) = 'E' then
(left(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1),100))),3) )
+
(SUBSTRING( LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1),100))),4 
,2)/60.0)
else
-1*(
(left(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1),100))),3) )
+
(SUBSTRING( LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1),100))),4 
,2)/60.0)
 )
 end
 end  longitude

,geography::Point(
     case when  CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)>0 then
        case when  right(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1)-1))),1) = 'N' then
        (left(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),2))
        +
        (SUBSTRING(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1)-1))),3,2)/60.0)
        else
        -1*(
        (left(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)-1))),2))
        +
        (SUBSTRING(LTrIM(RTRIM(left( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1)-1))),3,2)/60.0)
        )
        end
     end 
     ,case when  CHARINDEX(' ', @cord,1)>0 then
        case when right(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1),100))),1) = 'E' then
        (left(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1),100))),3) )
        +
        (SUBSTRING( LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1),100))),4 ,2)/60.0)
        else
        -1*(
        (left(LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1),100))),3) )
        +
        (SUBSTRING( LTrIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING( @cord, CHARINDEX(' ', 
 @cord,1),100))),4 ,2)/60.0)
        )
        end
    end  
    , 4326)  
      as geography_Point
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @user2621989 answer here is tested SQL Server version of his query:

```
DECLARE @longitude varchar(max) = '50°03''10"'
DECLARE @latitude varchar(max) = '15°00''50"'

SELECT 
CASE
WHEN LEN(@longitude)=8 THEN ROUND (cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 1, 1) as numeric(9,6)) +  cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 3, 2) as numeric(9,6))/60 +  cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 6, 2) as numeric(9,6))/3600,4) 
WHEN LEN(@longitude)=9  THEN ROUND (cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 1, 2) as numeric(9,6)) +  cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 4, 2) as numeric(9,6))/60 +  cast(SUBSTRING(@longitude, 7, 2) as numeric(9,6))/3600,4)
ELSE
ROUND (CAST (@longitude as numeric(9,6)),4)
END AS longitude,
CASE
WHEN LEN(@latitude)=8 THEN ROUND (cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 1, 1) as numeric(9,6)) +  cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 3, 2) as numeric(9,6))/60 +  cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 6, 2) as numeric(9,6))/3600,4) 
WHEN LEN(@latitude)=9  THEN ROUND (cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 1, 2) as numeric(9,6)) +  cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 4, 2) as numeric(9,6))/60 +  cast(SUBSTRING(@latitude, 7, 2) as numeric(9,6))/3600,4)
ELSE
ROUND (CAST (@latitude as numeric(9,6)),4)
END AS latitude
```

Returns

```
longitude       latitude
50.05280000000  15.01390000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example if your lat/lng parts are represented in separate columns: hemisphere, degrees, minutes, seconds.

```
/* 
lat/long sign key
+ + : North and East 
+ - : North and West 
- - : South and West 
- + : South and East
*/
SELECT
    ROUND(
        CASE WHEN LatitudeHemisphere = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END *
        ([LatitudeDegrees] + 
        (CAST([LatitudeMinutes] AS FLOAT)/60) + 
        (CAST([LatitudeSeconds] AS FLOAT)/3600)), 7, 1) AS Latitude,
    ROUND(
        CASE WHEN LongitudeHemisphere = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END *
        ([LongitudeDegrees] + 
        (CAST([LongitudeMinutes] AS FLOAT)/60) + 
        (CAST([LongitudeSeconds] AS FLOAT)/3600)), 7, 1) AS Longitude
    FROM [your_table]
```