# Convert DM lat long to decimal with MySql

Tags: mysql, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Im trying to convert my current position Lat: S3251 Long: W07122 position to degree format.
Ie Degrees Lat Long     -32.8500000, -071.3666667

This data is in mysql column like this:

### Name: Position:

Ship1    S3251 W07122

I am trying to figure out mysql query to display it like this:

### Name: Lat: Long:

Ship1   -32.8500000   -071.3666667

So I can use it on Google Maps, which requires Lat Long in decimals.

How do I convert this using mysql?
Thanks

Comment: Found it here, https://www.dougv.com/2012/03/converting-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-between-decimal-and-degrees-minutes-seconds/  how its done with php, but wondering if someone has mysql formula for this.

Comment: That doesn't look anything like the format you're converting.

Comment: I don't think there's a ready function in MySQL to do conversion. Especially with your lat long data seems to be non-standard (correct me if I'm wrong). You may have to apply the formula into your query but you have to make sure that your data is consistent and usable so that the calculation formula is correct.

Comment: found some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186110/converts-degrees-minutes-seconds-to-decimals-using-sql

Comment: Yes I know, its non standard, multiple agencies use this, and I need to fix it for them. There are bunch of online converters, that convert these with no problem. Just need to convert this to decimals. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Above samples are Degrees and Minutes. They are not Degrees Minutes Seconds. They each have S N E or W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a few functions to separate the data value to be used in the formula. Example query below:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN latt LIKE 'S%' THEN (SUBSTRING(latt,2,2)+(RIGHT(latt,2)/60)+(0/3600))*-1 
            WHEN latt LIKE 'N%' THEN SUBSTRING(latt,2,2)+(RIGHT(latt,2)/60)+(0/3600) END AS 'Latitude',
       CASE WHEN longt LIKE 'W%' THEN (SUBSTRING(longt,2,3)+(RIGHT(longt,2)/60)+(0/3600))*-1 
            WHEN longt LIKE 'E%' THEN SUBSTRING(longt,2,3)+(RIGHT(longt,2)/60)+(0/3600) END AS 'Longitude'
FROM test1;
```

As you can see, I'm using `CASE` expression to identify the direction, `SUBSTRING()` and `RIGHT()` functions to separate the degrees and minutes value for the formula.

P/S: Alternatively you can replace the `SUBSTRING()` with `MID()`. Both operates the same and the latter is considerably shorter to write.

This is using a formula from the [first link](https://www.dougv.com/2012/03/converting-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates-between-decimal-and-degrees-minutes-seconds/) you've provided in the comment:
[image]

I've made an example fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cJjaArst8aZmQesyWDDXim/1

Comment: Thanks, so much for this. Exactly what I was looking for. I dont understand, why so many down votes on my question.

Comment: You're welcome @Ossi, Glad I could help. About the down votes, I'm guessing maybe because you didn't give any attempted query? But it could also be caused a lot of other reasons. You may refer [here for more explanation on the matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).